# How can I make a div expand as the viewport pans around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` that acts as a viewport for a child `<div>`, in which the child `<div>` pans by clicking and dragging the mouse around, however I would like the child `<div>` to be filling the viewport, so that the edge of the child `<div>` is never visible. Example:

```js
var isDragging = false;
var lastMouseX;
var lastMouseY;

$("#viewport").mousedown(function(ev) {
  if (ev.which == 1) {
    isDragging = true;
  }
});

$("html").mouseup(function(ev) {
  if (ev.which == 1) {
    isDragging = false;
  }
});

$("#viewport").mousemove(function(e) {
  var deltaX = lastMouseX - e.clientX;
  var deltaY = lastMouseY - e.clientY;

  lastMouseX = e.clientX;
  lastMouseY = e.clientY;

  if (isDragging) {
    $("#view").css({
      left: "-=" + deltaX,
      top: "-=" + deltaY
    });
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#viewport {
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#view {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, white 1px, transparent 1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="viewport">
  <div id="view"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it "endless", as to constantly add a piece onto the child `<div>` whenever the viewport gets close to the edge?

**UPDATE:** To clarify my question, I want the child `<div>` to stay un-moving, so for the user, the child `div` should feel like an infinite plane which they look pan around. I don't want it to act like a `fixed` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this issue by creating a separate element that has the same grid background, but the background pans around with the child `<div>`. Snippet:

```js
var isDragging = false;
var lastMouseX;
var lastMouseY;

$("#viewport").mousedown(function(ev) {
  if (ev.which == 1) {
    isDragging = true;
  }
});

$("html").mouseup(function(ev) {
  if (ev.which == 1) {
    isDragging = false;
  }
});

$("#viewport").mousemove(function(e) {
  var deltaX = lastMouseX - e.clientX;
  var deltaY = lastMouseY - e.clientY;

  lastMouseX = e.clientX;
  lastMouseY = e.clientY;

  if (isDragging) {
    $("#view").css({
      left: "-=" + deltaX,
      top: "-=" + deltaY
    });
    $("#grid").css({
      'background-position-x': "-=" + deltaX,
      'background-position-y': "-=" + deltaY,
    });
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#viewport {
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#view {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#grid {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, white 1px, transparent 1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="viewport">
  <div id="grid"></div>
  <div id="view"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing width/height of the div along with its position

```
if (isDragging) {
  $("#view").css({
    left: "-=" + deltaX,
    top: "-=" + deltaY,
    width: "+=" + deltaX,
    height: "+=" + deltaY
});
```

Comment: I don't want it to act like a `fixed` element which follows the drag. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Alaanor You want child div to be followed up by exactly similar child div continuously.